# How to delete multiple texts with images in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have tried to delete both texts and images permanently from MySQL database with the following codes, I have spent almost a day on it did not know what I am doing wrong please help.

```php
public function multipleUserDelete(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod("post")) {
        $data = $request->all();
        // $postDelete=Post::where('id' ,'>' ,0)->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $postDeletes = Post::where('id', '>', 0)->get('post_image');

        foreach ($postDeletes as $postDelete) {
            # code...

            # code...
            // $postDeletes=Post::where(['id'=> $id])->get();
            //}
            $large_image_paths = 'images/backend_image/admin_users/small/';
            $medium_image_paths = 'images/backend_image/admin_users/medium/';
            $small_image_paths = 'images/backend_image/admin_users/large/';

            // Delete Image permenently from product table begins, Delete Large image if not exist
            if (file_exists($large_image_paths.$postDelete->post_image)) {
                unlink($large_image_paths.$postDelete->post_image);
            }

            // Delete Large image if not exist
            if (file_exists($small_image_paths.$postDelete->post_image)) {
                unlink($small_image_paths.$postDelete->post_image);
            }

            // Delete Medium image if not exist
            if (file_exists($medium_image_paths.$postDelete->post_image)) {

                unlink($medium_image_paths.$postDelete->post_image);
            }
        }

        //$del_id=$request->input('del_feedback');
        Post::whereIn('id', $data['del_user'])->delete();

        return redirect()->back()->with("flash_message_success", "you Successfully Deleted The Selected Users(s)");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem ? is it with the query ? or not unlinking from storage ?

Comment: the code is not working at all it brings this error"too fewer argument to function"

Comment: I think in one of you method `file_exists` the value is going null or empty, that's why it's saying `too fewer argument to function` can you please `dd()` any of your `$postDelete->post_image`